# Copy file to another folder with REST API in OneDrive pro (Sharepoint)

Tags: rest, sharepoint, copy, onedrive

I'm trying to copy a file located in user's personal folder (OneDrive Pro) using REST API. The resulting link seems to become too long (???) and server returns 400 BadRequest: The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.

Url looks like this (HTTP verb is POST):

```
https://<company>-my.sharepoint.com/personal/<user>_<company>_onmicrosoft_com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/personal/<user>_<company>_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/<Folder>/<Folder with guid-like name>/<filename>.pdf')/copyto(strnewurl='/personal/<user>_<company>_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/<Same folder>/<another guid-like name>/<same filename>.pdf',boverwrite=true)
```

Any help or advice on how to overcome this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if anyone else will face this problem and you will have unique id in your SP.

If first part, which is

```
GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/personal/<user>_<company>_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/<Folder>/<Folder with guid-like name>/<filename>.pdf')
```

will be replaced with `GetFileById(uniqueId)` the limitation would be satisfied and copy will succeed.